# RegEx how to insert text in a previous line of searched text in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am searching for an regular expression to insert text in previous line  below is the example how i need to insert in notepad++

```
submit...
action..
method=post
```

I would like to search with method=post and then insert a text "Post" like below
Always it should be two lines up of method=post

```
Post
Submit
action
method=post
```

Could you please suggest any regular expression I can use in notepad++?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want :
Use the Find & Replace Dialog Box. 
In Find What, add "method=post" and in Replace With add "Post^^submit^^action^^method=post"
And then Replace All.

Comment: Hi,I have tried this but its replacing like thissubmit
action
Post^^submit^^action^^method=post"

Comment: Make sure you chose "Regular expression" (bottom left corner of the Find / Replace box) and your version of Notepad++ must be greater than 6.6.3. i've tested and it works.

Answer (score 0):

This how I'd do the job:

Find what: `(.+\R.+\R.*method=post)`
Replace with: `Post\n$1`

Make sure you've selected `Regular Expression` and NOT checked `. matches newline`.